# REACT JEST error Cannot find module 'jest-matchers' from 'jest-expect.js'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When running tests getting the following error:

Cannot find module 'jest-matchers' from 'jest-expect.js'

```
  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)
```

Any ideas???

I'm using:

```
node@6.3.1
npm@4.0.5
jest@19.0.2
jest-matchers@19.0.0
```

Comment: Did you solve that one ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to run `npm ls` on your project's folder to see what dependencies you are missing

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and do an `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Add `node_modules` to `moduleDirectories`.

If you have a jest.config.js add it there,

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"]
};
```

otherwise should be added to package.json

```
"jest":{
  ...
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"]
}
```